# Spring Boot AOP in multi module project does not execute Before Advice

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-aop, multi-module

I'm doing my fist steps with Springs AOP and wanted to start with a simple logging advice. My project is a multi module maven project with the following structure:

parentProject
|__aop 
|__data 
|__web

The web module has a user service class in the package de.my.awsome.project.web.service with a saveNewUser Method:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
...
    public MdUser saveNewUser(UserModel user) {
        MdUser newUser = this.save(user);
        createGroupMembership(user, newUser);
        return newUser;
    }
}
```

The method works as expected so don't bother with details about that.

What I've done now is to create the following class in the aop module:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Before("execution(public * de.my.awsome.project.web.service.UserService.saveNewUser(..))")
    public void newUserLog(JoinPoint joinpoint) {
        logger.info(joinpoint.getSignature() + " with user " + joinpoint.getArgs()[0]);
}
```

}

I added a dependency for the web module in the pom of the aop module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.my.awsome.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I even wrote a ConfigurationClasse even though I thought this would not be necessary with SpringBoot:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.aop")
public class AspectsConfig {

}
```

The expected result is a log-message like "saveNewUser with user xyz". But the logging method is never called. What have I missed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer that @sankar posted didn't work either but I found the solution by myself.

I had to add a dependency to my aop module in the web modules pom, not vice versa. Then I added an Import of my AspectsConfig to the web modules SpringBootApplication class and it worked.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value= {JPAConfig.class, AspectsConfig.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WebApplication {

@Autowired
private JPAConfig config;

@Autowired
private AspectsConfig aspectConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration - Indicates that this file contains Spring Bean Configuration for an Aspect.

Replace @Component with @Configuration for LoggingAspect.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps work for me - see below if anyone is looking for a solution

1. add the aop dependency in to the main parent pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2. add your Aspect implementation in he aop-sub-module

```
   @Aspect
   @Component
   public class SampleAspect {

    @After("execution(* de.my.awsome.project.testMethod())") 
    public void logAuditActivity(JoinPoint jp) { 
     System.out.println("TESTING ****************");
     System.out.println("The method is called");

   }
```

3. In your other submodule  (web-submodule) add the dependancy of the aspect-submodule

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.my.awsome.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

4. In your web Project include the aop package for component scan
   eg. if SampleAspect is under a package de.my.awsome.project you will need to add in as follow

```
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.my.awsome.project", "de.my.awsome.aop" }
```

5. clean build and run the app